# I can't fetch data from two different collection consecutively in Firebase with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to fetch from two different collection but I got a weird situation. First, I want to fetch a userID from posts collection. Then with that userID, I want to fetch data from users collection.

So, when I fetch from only the posts collection, print command works perfectly fine and prints the userID.

But when I add the users fetch statement that I showed in the code below it doesn't fetch it and shows an empty string (''), and users collection sends an error because I couldn't search the userID. What am I missing here?

```
class _ProductDetail extends State<ProductDetail> {
  String getTitle = '';
  String getLocation = '';
  String getPrice = '';
  String getImage = '';
  String getUniversity = '';
  String getProfileImage = '';
  String getUserName = '';
  String getSellerUserID = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(widget.postID)
        .get()
        .then((incomingData) {
      setState(() {
        getTitle = incomingData.data()!['title'];
        getPrice = incomingData.data()!['price'];
        getImage = incomingData.data()!['postImage'];
      });
    });
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(widget.postID)
        .get()
        .then((incomingData) {
      setState(() {
        getSellerUserID = incomingData.data()!['userID'];
      });
    });
    print(getSellerUserID); //statement that will print the userID

    //////////////////////IF I DELETE THIS SECTION, IT PRINTS THE USER ID//////////////////
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(getSellerUserID)
        .get()
        .then((incomingData) {
      setState(() {
        getUserName = incomingData.data()!['username'];
        getProfileImage = incomingData.data()!['profileImage'];
        getUniversity = incomingData.data()!['university'];
        getLocation = incomingData.data()!['location'];
      });
    });
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    return Scaffold(
    ....... rest of the code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously, the code inside your `then` blocks is called (way) later then the line after the call to `get()`.

To see this most easily, add some logging like this:

```
print("Before calling Firestore")
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('posts')
    .doc(widget.postID)
    .get()
    .then((incomingData) {
  print("Got data")
});
print("After calling Firestore")
```

If you run this code, it'll print:

> Before calling Firestore
>
> After calling Firestore
>
> Got data

This is probably not the order you expected, but does explain why your next load from the database doesn't work: the `getSellerUserID = incomingData.data()!['userID']` line hasn't been run yet by that time.

For this reason: any code that needs the data from Firestore, needs to be inside the `then` (or `onSnapshot`) handler, be called from there, or be otherwise synchronized.

---

So the simplest fix is to move the next database call *into* the `then:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('posts')
    .doc(widget.postID)
    .get()
    .then((incomingData) {
  var sellerUserID = incomingData.data()!['userID'];
  setState(() {
    getSellerUserID = sellerUserID;
  });
  print(sellerUserID);

  FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(sellerUserID)
    .get()
    .then((incomingData) {
    setState(() {
      getUserName = incomingData.data()!['username'];
      getProfileImage = incomingData.data()!['profileImage'];
      getUniversity = incomingData.data()!['university'];
      getLocation = incomingData.data()!['location'];
    });
  });
});
```